# Pass value from window.prompt to server with ajax or javascript

Tags: javascript, php

I want a help with this important thing.
I want to pass the value from a window.prompt to server through ajax or javascript (i dont know which of these 2 can be easy..)
I am reading now that i have to use a hidden input(like a text with type=hidden) in a form, in order to pass the data to server.

Can anyone help me with this, because i'm not an experienced programmer and i can't do it by my own? I made a try but with no result..

selectfrm.html:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="select.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<button id="button2" onclick="myFunction()">Select by ID</button>
<div id="content"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

select.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#button2").click(function() {

        function show_selected() {
            var id=$("#id").val();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "select.php",
                data:{action:id},
                success: function (data) {
                    $("#content").html(data);
                    $("#button").hide();
                }
            });
        }

        show_selected();
    });
});

function myFunction()
{
    var id = window.prompt("Give the userid");

}
```

select.php

```
<?php
$link=mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "mysql3");

if (mysqli_connect_errno())
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL:" .mysqli_connect_error();

$action=$_POST["action"];

    $query = "SELECT * FROM components WHERE user_id = '$action'";
    $show = mysqli_query($link, $query) or die ("Error");
    echo "<table border='2px'><tr><td>name_id</td><td>name</td><td>age</td></tr>";
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($show)) {
        echo "<tr><td>" .$row['book_id'] ."</td><td>" .$row['game_id'] ."</td><td>" .$row['site_id'] ."</td></tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found the solution. Here it is:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#button2").click(function() {
        var ut = prompt("Some");
        function show_selected() {
            var id=$("#id").val();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "select.php",
                data:{action:ut},
                success: function (data) {
                    $("#content").html(data);
                    $("#button").hide();
                }
            });
        }

        show_selected();
    });
});
testAjax(function(output){
  window.alert("ut");// here you use the output
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<br>
<input type="text" id="id" />
<button id="button2">Select by ID</button>
<div id="content"></div>
</body>
</html>
```